# iOS: NSURL resourceValues ubiquitousItemIsShared not returning expected value

Tags: ios, swift, file, icloud, nsurl

I'm trying to work out if an item represented by an NSURL has been shared with the current user via iCloud.

I receive the NSURL from the UIApplication delegate method

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return url.isShared()
}
```

Where my extension is defined as:

```
extension URL {

    public func isShared() -> Bool {

        do {
            let values = try self.resourceValues(forKeys: [.ubiquitousItemIsSharedKey])
            if let isShared = values.ubiquitousItemIsShared {
                print("ubiquitousItemIsShared is \(isShared)")
                return isShared
            } else {
                print("ubiquitousItemIsShared is nil")
                return false
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to get resourceValues: \(error)")
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

When I test this code, I do the following from the Files app.

- Open file "On my iPad"
- Open file "Shared by John Appleseed"

However both of these files (one on the device and the other shared), print the same thing in the console: **ubiquitousItemIsShared is nil** meaning `values.ubiquitousItemIsShared` is nil.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried `promisedItemResourceValues(forKeys:)` instead of `resourceValues(forKeys:)`, given you're dealing with ubiquitous data?

Comment: Great idea. Same result unfortunately :(